# scala: not possible to match on value expressions?

Tags: scala

Why isn't it possible to place expressions in case statements? :

```
  x match {
    case <VALUE EXPR> => {}
  }
```

For example

```
  x match {
    case (1+2) => {}
  }
```

is not allowed, but

```
  val someval = (1+new java.util.Random().nextInt())

  x match {
    case someval => {}
  }
```

is. It seems that if the second case is allowed, so should the first.

I'm trying to add a list of mappings like this:

```
  val typ:Type = symbol.typeSignature

  typ match {
    case typeOf[collection.immutable.List[Any]] => { return a function to handle this type }
    case typeOf[...] => {}
    case typeOf[...] => {}
    ... many
  }
```

Comment: Note that `case someval` doesn't do what you expect, it'll match anything because it creates a new variable. To change this, you need to capitalize variable name or surround it with backticks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It simply defies the definition of **patterns** in pattern matching.

From the [Scala Language Specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf), chapter 8:

> A pattern is built from constants, constructors, variables and type tests

"Expressions" is not in this list, and that makes some sense - think about it - when will this expression be evaluated? What if it has side-effects, will it be evaluated even if a case preceding it was used to return the result?

A valid workaround is using a **guard**, which *is* evaluated:

```
x match {
  case i if i == (1+2) => {} // works as expected...
}
```